# rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds ! (but it should be receiving !)

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rtabmap-odometry, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using `ros-noetic-desktop-full/focal,now 1.5.0-1focal.20200826.205403 amd64 [installed]` on Ubuntu 20

rtabmap says it's not receiving data but the topics it's subscribed to are sending data.

```
[ INFO] [1599753269.979982470]: Odom: quality=374, std dev=0.008319m|0.038960rad, update time=0.048805s
[ INFO] [1599753270.384529419]: Odom: quality=366, std dev=0.008452m|0.027549rad, update time=0.055490s
[ INFO] [1599753270.783139929]: Odom: quality=382, std dev=0.008427m|0.036256rad, update time=0.054365s
[ INFO] [1599753270.980215457]: Odom: quality=381, std dev=0.009444m|0.027549rad, update time=0.052128s
[ INFO] [1599753271.187793313]: Odom: quality=366, std dev=0.009227m|0.041195rad, update time=0.057325s
[ INFO] [1599753271.582514826]: Odom: quality=361, std dev=0.008557m|0.032761rad, update time=0.052902s
[ INFO] [1599753271.782553265]: Odom: quality=375, std dev=0.008748m|0.036256rad, update time=0.051991s
[ WARN] [1599753272.071042131]: /rtabmap/rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). If topics are not published at the same rate, you could increase "queue_size" parameter (current=5000).
/rtabmap/rtabmap subscribed to (approx sync):
   /stereo_odometry,
   /stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color,
   /stereo_camera/right/image_rect,
   /stereo_camera/left/camera_info,
   /stereo_camera/right/camera_info
[ INFO] [1599753272.190012838]: Odom: quality=359, std dev=0.008809m|0.027549rad, update time=0.056297s
[ INFO] [1599753272.393765113]: Odom: quality=374, std dev=0.008249m|0.036256rad, update time=0.061737s
```

I can see the odometry with rtabmapviz and as you can see it's working (well ?) . I've check all 5 topics one by one because multiple topic checks fails with this

```
rostopic hz /stereo_odometry /stereo_camera/left/image_rect /stereo_camera/left/camera_info
subscribed to [/stereo_odometry]
subscribed to [/stereo_camera/left/image_rect]
subscribed to [/stereo_camera/left/camera_info]
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/rostopic",
line 35, in <module>
    rostopic.rostopicmain()   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py",
line 2132, in rostopicmain
    _rostopic_cmd_hz(argv)   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py",
line 1523, in _rostopic_cmd_hz
    _rostopic_hz(topics, window_size=window_size,
filter_expr=filter_expr,   File
"/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py",
line 323, in _rostopic_hz
    rt.print_hz(topics)   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py",
line 270, in print_hz
    print(_get_ascii_table(header, stats))   File
"/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rostopic/__init__.py",
line 285, in _get_ascii_table
    body = '\n'.join('   '.join(cols[h][i] for h in header) for
i in xrange(n_rows)) NameError: name
'xrange' is not defined
```

So after checking the topics one by one all of them are publishing data at about 4-5 messages per second. I'm lost :) . Am I misunderstanding the message somehow ?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361312/rtabmap:-did-not-receive-data-since-5-seconds-!-(but-it-should-be-receiving-!)/) by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-12**:
I managed to "fix" the error with rostopic by just renaming xrange() to range()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For rtabmap node, try with `approx_sync:=false` as you are using stereo data (which should be exactly synchronized). You can also try to increase the `queue_size`. Note also that on Noetic, we got some issues with `message_filters` not able to synchronize some topics for some unknown reasons. We did a [fix recently](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/ed564c3a12293d06ca28e145ff50a974f6159cc9) to set the `queue_size` of individual subscribers (which was 1 before like in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#ApproximateTime_Policy)) with same `queue_size` of the sync policy. This fix is not in binaries yet, you would have to build `rtabmap_ros` from source:

```
$ sudo apt remove ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rtabmap-ros
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros.git
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make
```

If you have compilation errors with rtabmap library, you will have to build rtabmap from source too:

```
$ sudo apt remove ros-$ROS_DISTRO-rtabmap
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap.git
$ cd ~/rtabmap/build
$ cmake ..
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

Then go back try building your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-12**:
The first thing (approx_sync) didn't work. It even complains about it now :) . And the queue_size is already 5000.... I'll try to rebuild rtabmap-ros  now and see what happens

```
[ INFO] [1599909781.316510633]: Odom: quality=404, std dev=0.004559m|0.027549rad, update time=0.046234s
[ WARN] [1599909781.590796230]: /rtabmap/rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). Parameter "approx_sync" is false, which means that input topics should have all the exact timestamp for the callback to be called.
```

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-12**:
I had to hard code PCL_ROOT to "/usr" after :

```
file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${PCL_DIR}" PCL_DIR)
if(WIN32 AND NOT MINGW)
# PCLConfig.cmake is installed to PCL_ROOT/cmake
  get_filename_component(PCL_ROOT "${PCL_DIR}" PATH)
else()
# PCLConfig.cmake is installed to PCL_ROOT/share/pcl-x.y
  get_filename_component(PCL_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../.." ABSOLUTE)
endif()
```

CMake was supposed to be a fix / better to "configure" scripts lol. Not getting there any time soon I guess :)

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-12**:
Well basically nothing changed with the new 'rtabmap_ros' :) I fixed the 'rostopic' this is the output.

```
               topic                    rate   min_delta   max_delta   std_dev    window
========================================================================================
/stereo_odometry                       5.006   0.184       0.2092      0.007313   21
/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color   5.001   0.1925      0.2051      0.003302   21
/stereo_camera/left/camera_info        5.0     0.1952      0.2059      0.002057   20
/stereo_camera/right/image_rect        5.0     0.1823      0.2169      0.007288   20
/stereo_camera/right/camera_info       5.0     0.1959      0.2036      0.001369   20
```

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-09-15**:
A `queue_size` of 5000 is too huge, keep it at 10 by default. Sorry I messed up the answer, you should build master branch of rtabmap_ros to have the latest fixes (I'll update the answer).

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-17**:
I guess I have to - it needs rtabmap 0.20.2 and the package is "ros-noetic-rtabmap/focal,now 0.20.0-3focal.20200812.201538 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]"

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-09-17**:
Yeah, I added this detail to the answer too, rebuild also rtabmap.

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-17**:
Did it - I had to add 4 more Gigs to the test machine apparently for C++ 4GB RAM (I even killed the X server) is not enough - one of the (many) reasons I prefer C :)
So I got to here (Odometry still works fine):

```
[FATAL] (2020-09-17 22:14:33.619) Features2d.cpp:745::generateDescriptors() Condition (descriptors.rows == (int)keypoints.size()) not met! [descriptors=0, keypoints=1000]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'UException'
  what():  [FATAL] (2020-09-17 22:14:33.619) Features2d.cpp:745::generateDescriptors() Condition (descriptors.rows == (int)keypoints.size()) not met! [descriptors=0, keypoints=1000]
```

Any ideas ? Thank you for the help so far ! :)

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-21**:
"Fixed" the problem - BRIEF was not available. But I got it to here - buffer overflow sounds like a problem :)

```
[ INFO] [1600704092.320869806]: rtabmap (1): Rate=1.00s, Limit=0.700s, RTAB-Map=0.1281s, Maps update=0.0017s pub=0.0004s (local map=1, WM=1)
[ INFO] [1600704092.395859803]: Odom: quality=417, std dev=0.010630m|0.000032rad, update time=0.027884s
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
[rtabmap/rtabmap-7] process has died [pid 50201, exit code -6, cmd /home/tbyte/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/rtabmap --delete_db_on_start left/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color right/image_rect:=/stereo_camera/right/image_rect left/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/left/camera_info right/camera_info:=/stereo_camera/right/camera_info odom:=/stereo_odometry __name:=rtabmap
```

**Comment by [Kendolph](https://answers.ros.org/users/59245/kendolph/) on 2020-09-21**:
Got it to work at last ! Recompiled rtabmap_ros with DEBUG, did not help but I saw that it is crashing somewhere in TF2.  Upgraded to the latest ros-noetic from packages and installed debug symbols for TF2 ... and now it works. I'll try to remove all of the debug and see what happens.
PS: It still works without debug.